# Точка после вставной конструкции в конце предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно оформить предложение со вставной конструкцией в конце: с точкой или без?

> Я хотел поздравить вас с днем рождения (Маркову на момент написания письма было шестьдесят лет. — И. Е.).

или

> Я хотел поздравить вас с днем рождения (Маркову на момент написания письма было шестьдесят лет. — И. Е.)

---

*И. Е. — инициалы автора книги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем нам помешала вставная конструкция? У неё свои знаки, у предложения свои.

Подумайте, как точка после инициала может указать нам, что предложение - повествовательное?

Совершенно верен первый вариант:

*Я хотел поздравить вас с днем рождения (Маркову на момент написания письма было шестьдесят лет. — И. Е.).*

И не может быть никакого правила для очевидных вещей.

И предложение перестраивать совершенно излишне.

Первое правило редактора: ЕСЛИ **МОЖНО** НЕ ПРАВИТЬ, **НУЖНО** НЕ ПРАВИТЬ!

Answer (score 3):

*(Маркову на момент написания письма было шестьдесят лет. — И. Е.)* — совершенно самостоятельное предложения, к тому же ещё и с пояснением.

Думаю, что здесь лучше использовать такое правило:
Вставная конструкция, будучи самостоятельным предложением (текст вставки после открывающей скобки начинается с прописной буквы), выделяется скобками. Перед скобкой, открывающей вставку, ставится необходимый по условиям контекста знак конца предложения. Перед закрывающей скобкой ставится знак, фиксирующий конец вставного предложения.

***...Так будет дальновиднее... (У Маслова клокотало в горле, хотя говорит он тихо и даже вяло.)***
[**Знаки препинания при вставках. § 99**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128)

*Как будто ей подмигнул сам Всевышний. (Вот что значит магия того дня – Мэтью, кольцо… хотя, если здраво рассудить, какая тут связь?)*
Р. Гэлбрейт. Зов кукушки

Я бы оформила предложение так (у вас нет этого варианта):
*Я хотел поздравить вас с днем рождения. (Маркову на момент написания письма было шестьдесят лет. — И. Е.)*

Comment: Предложенные варианты я рассматривал,однако мне нужно знать: есть ли ошибка в исходном оформлении.

Comment: Правильно: Я хотел поздравить вас с днем рождения (Маркову на момент написания письма было шестьдесят лет. — И. Е.).  "Знаки конца основного предложения (точка, вопросительный и восклицательный знак) выносятся за закрывающую вставку скобку".

Comment: Самое интересное: отвечала Вам и нашла ответ на СВОЙ вопрос. Как Вы думаете, стоит его оформить? (О скобках в начале предложения...)

Comment: Как пожелаете )

Answer (score 1):

Скобка, закрывающая вставную конструкцию, не может заканчивать предложение: точка безусловно нужна. Не будет хуже, если выделенное скобками задвинуть внутрь фразы:

«Я хотел поздравить Вас (Маркову на момент написания письма было шестьдесят лет. — И.Е.) с днем рождения.»

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести источник, подтверждающий это? (Несмотря на то, что я согласен с вами, это окажется полезным.) И еще: важно сохранить устройство предложения нетронутым.

Comment: Теперь я понимаю, это были ученические работы, даже, может быть, просто мазня… (Кат.). 
Это из § 1. Знаки препинания в конце предложения Лопатина В.В.

Comment: спасибо за наводку, завтра полистаю.